# Alternatives to sqlcmd/best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a sql query that updates certain tables taking a CSV file as the input.

I want my co-workers to be able to execute this query as easily as possible. At first, I thought a batch file using sqlcmd was the best solution.

The end product works on my computer, because I have SSMS installed, but no other computer is able to properly launch the batch file.

What is the best way for my end-users to run an sql query? I have thought/researched these solutions:

-Install SSMS or the required tools(don't want each user to have to do this.)

-Install Psexec tools to allow for remote batch launching (also don't like this.)

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a C-Sharp or VB.Net program that executes the proc and distribute the program to your users?

Comment: I already have the xlsm file execute the batch file, they're not double clicking it or anything if that's what you mean. If I misunderstood you, could you explain further?

Comment: If you want to allow users to easily execute a stored procedure in your database (using Bulk Insert) you can build the command in a Csharp program and then pass it into sql server to execute the proc (perhaps with a paramater that contains the file location) - Your program can pass into SQL Server a SQLCommand

Answer (score 2):

Check SQLS*Plus from www.memfix.com - works the best.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install all of SMS. You can just install SQLServer2008CmdLnUtilsx86.msi for SQL 2008 or go here to get SQLCMD for SQL 2012. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36433. Just be aware that if you install SQLCMD in a bat file and then attempt to use SQLCMD after installing it in that same bat file you have to specify full path to SQLCMD because PATH value is loaded at time bat was started and SQLCMD was not yet available at that time.

Comment: did you tested it?

Comment: Yes... it works. If you install in bat file and then attempt to use SQLCMD after installing it in that same bat file you have to reboot or specify full path to SQLCMD because PATH value is loaded at time bat was started and SQLCMD was not yet available at that time.